# How to find RMSE by using loop in R

Tags: r, statistics, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

If I have a data frame contain 3 variables :

```r
origdata <- data.frame(
  age <- c(22, 45, 50, 80, 55, 45, 60, 24,   18, 15),
  bmi <- c(22, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 27, 25.5, 18, 25),
  hyp <- c(1,  2,  4,  3,  1,  2,  1,  5,    4,  5) )
```

I created MCAR (missing complete at random) data :

```r
halpha <- 0.1

# MCAR for attribute (1) age:
mcar <- runif(10, min = 0, max = 1)  
age.mcar <- ifelse(mcar < alpha, NA, origdata$age)  

# MCAR for attribute (2) bmi: 
mcar <- runif(10, min = 0, max = 1) 
bmi.mcar <- ifelse(mcar < alpha, NA, origdata$bmi)  

# MCAR for attribute (3) hyp: 
mcar <- runif(10, min = 0, max = 1) 
hyp.mcar <- ifelse(mcar < alpha, NA, origdata$hyp)
```

After that I used the `mice` package to impute the missing value as follows:

```r
install.packages("mice")
library("mice")
imp <- mice(df, 10)              # 10 is mean 10 iteration imputing data 
fill1 <- complete(imp, 1)        # dataset 1
fill2 <- complete(imp, 2)        # dataset 2
allfill <- complete(imp, "long") # all iterations together
```

My question is: I want to find RMSE for all 10 datasets individually by using a loop. This is my RMSE equation :

```r
RMSE <- sqrt((sum((origdata - fill)^2)) / sum(is.na(df)))
```

I mean to make a loop to find the RMSE for each imputed dataset individually:
RMSE1 (for dataset #1)
RMSE2 (for dataset #2)
...
RMSE10 (for dataset #10)

And I also want to know which dataset is best for impute `NA`s.

Comment: Why would the RMSE be informative about which run of imputation is "best". Seems as though that would be a classic case of "begging the question". I think you need statistical advice more than you need programming assistance.

Comment: Typically if one is doing multiple imputation, model-averaging is used after running analyses on each imputed dataset. One typically does not choose a "best" imputation in the manner you have described.

Comment: ok you think RMSE is not best tool  to check that which imputation is best . give me advice which are new tools for know that which imputation is best .

Comment: @Alex did you mean by this way   
                                                                          
`fit <- with(imp2, lm(ch1.mcar~age.mcar+bmi.mcar))
                                                                                                                pool(fit)
                                                                                             summary(pool(fit))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

loop in R:

```r
m <- imp$m  # number of imputations

RSME <- rep(NA, m)
for (i in seq_len(m)) {
  fill <- complete(imp, i)
  RMSE[i] <- (sqrt((sum((orgdata - fill)^2))/sum(is.na(x))))
}
```